# Node + Express + Multer: upload array where some elements are null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I want to upload an array of files, but some elements can be null/undefined. Multer ignores the null files. Is there a way to make Multer maintain the index of non-null files?

E.g. if I upload an array where the first element is null and the second is a file:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarydFfDIpmAwbAA7GSS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photos"
null
------WebKitFormBoundarydFfDIpmAwbAA7GSS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photos"; filename="photo.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

In my request handler, I'd receive an array with 1 element. I wouldn't know if this was the first or second element:

```
 [
   {
     fieldname: 'photos',
     originalname: 'photo.jpg',
     encoding: '7bit',
     mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
     destination: '/tmp',
     filename: '24c944fd7975c503c4cc4add4f447aaf',
     path: '/tmp/24c944fd7975c503c4cc4add4f447aaf',
     size: 837080
   }
 ]
```

Is there a way to make Multer make the first array element `null`?

Comment: Please paste code for HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know your code but it should be multer settings

```
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png'){
        cb(null, true)
    }else{
        cb(new Error('should be png or jpeg'), false)
    }
}
const multerStorage = multer.memoryStorage();

const upload = multer({
    storage: multerStorage,
    fileFilter: fileFilter
});
```

it should be coming request;

images => request payload data

35 => coming image quantity

```
router.put('/update', upload.array("images", 35), (req, res)
```

I hope it helped

Comment: `fileFilter` doesn't seem to work, null in the array never gets passed to it

Comment: you need to send formData in html side

Comment: Yeah, there's the raw formData in the question